# How to display JSON data from API with VUE

Tags: json, api, vue.js, axios

How can I display the names of the pokemon that I get from this Pokeapi: https://pokeapi.co/

```
<template>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="name in info">
        <span >{{ name }}</span>
    </div>  
</div>

</template> 

<script>
    export default {
    el: '#app',

    data () {
        return {
            info: [],
            loading: true,
            errored: false
        }
    },

    mounted () {
        axios

        .get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')

        .then(response => {
            this.info = response.data.results
        })

        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            this.errored = true
        })

        .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    }
};
</script>
```

I expect to be able to display for example the name bulbasaur and the url that is givin within the API.

Currently this is displaying:

```
{ "name": "bulbasaur", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/" }
{ "name": "ivysaur", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/" }
{ "name": "venusaur", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/" }
{ "name": "charmander", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "name" in your for loop is referencing the object itself since info is an array of objects. Use dot notation to access the value you want to display. for example

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="pokemon in info">
        <span >{{ pokemon.name }}</span>
        <span >{{ pokemon.url }}</span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I how would I take the url, and then use it to make another call to the api to get information specifically about that pokemon?

Comment: Well, that would depend entirely upon how/when you wish you make the api call.

Are you clicking a load info button? Or is the api going to be called as soon as an element is rendered? If the api call is event based, you can create a method that takes the url as an argument and fetches the data then attach the method to an event listener. 

If you want the information straight away, I would suggest creating a separate Pokemon component that accepts the url as a prop and makes a call to the api in the mounted() lifecycle hook using the url prop. There are many ways to solve that problem.